# HOW to use animation Attribute `controlX1` in API level lower than 21

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

As the question says, Is there any workarounds to use `controlX1` animation attribute in android in API lower than 21

```
<pathInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:controlX1="0.4"
              android:controlY1="0"
              android:controlX2="0.2"
              android:controlY2="1"/>
```

Comment: `PathInterpolatorCompat` ?

Comment: is there such thing?

Comment: i beg your pardon?

Comment: i will give it a try and let u know